# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level - tokenize, line 8

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import calendar

def leapyr(year1, year2):
    count = 0
    while year1 <= year2:
        if calendar.isleap(year1) == True:
            count = count + 1
        year1 = year1 + 1 
    print count

leapyr(2008, 1015)
```

i have no bloody idea why this doesnt work. I tried "python -m tabnanny thefile.py" it tells me "indentation error: ((tokenize), line 8)" but i have no idea what to make of that information.

Comment: The `while` block is never entered for `leapyr(2008, 1015)` by the way

Comment: I'm going to take a guess and say you're mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: I'm not getting the error on Linux or Windows

Comment: @MorganThrapp yup, that probably the most likely reason. The indention looks fine.

Comment: you copy the space before 'if' in line 6 and paste it in line 8.. just to make sure that both if and line 8 have same intendation level

Comment: here is the link to actual working version: https://repl.it/Dpyr/0

Answer (score 4):

Python allows mixing tabs and spaces. Before interpreting the source, python interpreter replaces tabs with spaces in such way that each tab is aligned to 8 spaces (see [the doc on indentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation)).

If your editor is set to show tabs as 8 spaces, that should actually work as expected, but if it shows tabs as 4 spaces, then what it looks like is nothing like what the interpreter sees.

The code from the question is:

---

`import calendar`

`def leapyr(year1, year2):`

<kbd>4 spaces</kbd>`count = 0`

<kbd>4 spaces</kbd>`while year1 <= year2:`

<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>4 spaces</kbd>`if calendar.isleap(year1) == True:`

<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>4 spaces</kbd>`count = count + 1`

<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>`year1 = year1 + 1`

<kbd>tab</kbd>`print count`

<kbd>tab</kbd>

`leapyr(2008, 1015)`

---

That is interpreted by Python as:

```
import calendar

def leapyr(year1, year2):
    count = 0
    while year1 <= year2:
            if calendar.isleap(year1) == True:
                    count = count + 1
                year1 = year1 + 1 
        print count

leapyr(2008, 1015)
```

This has an indentation error in line 8, at `year1 = year1 + 1`.

The solution is to configure the editor to always use spaces, i.e. to replace tabs with 4 spaces.

Comment: BTW, StackOverflow shows tabs as 4 spaces. I clicked *edit* on the question to get the actual source.

Comment: Note that this is specific to Python 2. Python 3 would complain immediately when it encountered mixed tabs and spaces. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295519/indentation-error-with-python-3-3-when-python2-7-works-well about that.